# Saving a PDF output of Flask Web app after completing a form and signature

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pdf-generation, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that delivers a web-page with a signature canvas.  I need to save a PDF output of this document, with signature, to a MySQL database.  I am currently using Flask, Javascript and SQL Alchemy but am open to other options if it will make the end result easier.  The print to PDF function in Chrome accomplishes this perfectly, just need to automate it and get it to the server.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image: screenshot of app so far]

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no much information available, i'm going to try to help a bit. First store that canvas in `BASE64` data and send it back to server in ajax request or append field in your form for sending it on form submit.

Here is some piece of code for javascript:

```
let canvasPayload = canvas.toDataURL();
```

hope this helps a little.

Comment: This is helpful! Thanks!  What I wanted would be the equivalent of the Print-to-PDF function the browser to be returned back to the server where it could then be placed into a MySQL database.  The goal is to replace a scanned copy of the form but the result should be nearly identical to what would have been a scanned printout.